# Woocommerce add to cart button link is being cached by the browser

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, browser-cache

lightningfastcells.com is using woocommerce plugin. Now when adding a product to cart it works and redirects to (?add-to-cart=457) but when I add the same product by clicking on the add to cart link the page is being cached by the browser thus it doesn't add the product to the cart but when I refresh the page or revisit the link (?add-to-cart=457) it adds the product to cart. Is there a way to disable cache on add to cart links?

Comment: Just run into this issue too. Works fine if I disable cache in browser dev tools, but otherwise fails. (I'm also not using any caching plugins). Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using w3total cache then pls check below docs

https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/configuring-caching-plugins/

Comment: I'm not using any caching plugin